# How to check cross-object formula usage count?

Tags: formula-field

Salesforce allows a maximum of **10 unique relationships per object** in cross-object formulas per https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_cross_object_notes.htm&language=en_US

But how do I find the current usage (I mean the count)? I tried checking in the "**Object Limits**" section but it is not present in there. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it's actually listed in the limits area, probably because it is a soft limit and can be increased by SalesForce, but one way to see where they are used and how many are used is to intentionally break the limit and then click on the "Show References" link.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jenny. Could you please explain about types of limits like soft limit?

Comment: Limits that you can usually get SalesForce support to increase without additional charges, from what I understand you can ask them to increase this limit but it's recommended to try and limit these if you can.

Comment: I really with SF would provide an interface to check this without having to create a formula and force an exception.